# Deno 1.1.1 Static HTTP Server

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, deno

I have been reading about Deno for a few hours and finally got an http static server running.

I would like to know what else is needed to add https to it.

I understand Leaf to Root arrangement of certificates but not in Deno.

[image: sc]

Working code:

```
import {
  gray,
  green,
  cyan,
  bold,
  yellow,
  red,
} from 'https://deno.land/std@0.58.0/fmt/colors.ts';

import { Application, HttpError, send, Status } from 'https://deno.land/x/oak/mod.ts';

const app = new Application();

// Middleware 1 - Error handler
app.use(async (context, next) => {
  try {
    await next();

  } catch (e) {

    if (e instanceof HttpError) {
      context.response.status = e.status as any;
      // expose
      // Determines if details about the error should be automatically exposed in a response.
      // This is automatically set to true for 4XX errors, as they represent errors in the request...
      if (e.expose) {
        context.response.body = `
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
          <body>
            <h1>${e.status} - ${Status[e.status]}</h1>
            <!-- <h1>${e.status} - ${e.message}</h1> -->
          </body>
        </html>`;
      } else {
        context.response.body = `
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
          <body>
            <h1>${e.status} - ${Status[e.status]}</h1>
            <!-- <h1>${e.status} - ${e.message}</h1> -->
          </body>
        </html>`;
      }

    } else if (e instanceof Error) {
      context.response.status = 500;
      // ...while 5XX errors are set to false as they are internal server errors and 
      // exposing details could leak important server security information.
      context.response.body = `
      <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
        <body>
          <h1>500 - Internal Server Error</h1>
        </body>
      </html>`;
      console.log('Unhandled Error:', red(bold(e.message)));
      console.log(e.stack);
    }
  }
});

// Middleware 2 - Logger
app.use(async (context, next) => {
  await next();
  const rt = context.response.headers.get('X-Response-Time');
  console.log(`${green(context.request.method)} ${cyan(context.request.url.pathname)} - ${bold(String(rt),)}`, );
});

// Middleware 3 - Response Time
app.use(async (context, next) => {
  const start = Date.now();
  await next();
  const ms = Date.now() - start;
  context.response.headers.set('X-Response-Time', `${ms}ms`);
});

// End point - Send static content
app.use(async (context) => {
  await context.send({
    root: `${Deno.cwd()}/var/www/example1.com/public`,
    index: 'index.html',
  });
});

// Welcome message
app.addEventListener('listen', ({ hostname, port }) => {

  console.clear();

  console.log(' ');
  console.log(bold('Deno 1.1.1 - Static HTTP Server'));
  console.log(gray('  @host: ') + yellow(`${hostname}`));
  console.log(gray('  @port: ') + yellow(`${port}`));
  console.log(gray(' Status: ') + green('online'));
  console.log(gray('  @root: ') + cyan('/var/www/example1.com/public'));
  console.log(gray(' @index: ') + cyan('index.html'));
  console.log(' ');

});

await app.listen({ hostname: '127.0.0.1', port: 80 });

// run the server
// deno run --allow-net --allow-read httpServer.ts
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the documentation on [serveTLS](https://doc.deno.land/https/deno.land/std/http/server.ts#serveTLS) and [listenAndServeTLS](https://doc.deno.land/https/deno.land/std/http/server.ts#listenAndServeTLS).

If you have a valid certificate, you shouldn't have any issues. However, I had some difficulty [overriding rejections of self-signed SSL certificates](https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/5931). Also, I ended up serving ssl on [a port other than 443](https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/5816#issuecomment-635528888), due to [permission errors](https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/5816) I received while trying to run an HTTPS server as a local user.

Those are the issues I ran into and how I got around them. I hope it helps.

Comment: Testing the http server in ubuntu 19.04 right now and getting lots of permission denied. It works in windows.

Comment: I have just tried it as root and it works. I can't get it to run as a sudo user.

Comment: And... I finally understand why you would still wanna use NGINX as a proxy server. If you're coming from `NGINX + PHP-FPM` Deno would be replacing `PHP-FPM`.As of 1.1.1, Deno simply cannot compete with NGINX when it comes to `https`. The deno https server blew up after I've run a ssl test on it; just testing it for ssl crashed it. NGINX is a beast; a tall, lean, mean machine of robust, time tested, `C` goodness. They can better work together one as a proxy to the other.

Comment: @suchislife : I agree. Deno SSL is not ready for prime time in version 1. To me, deno is just a toy until it allows the developer to decide what makes a certificate "bad" (like node.js allows). Plus, Nginx definitely offers superior performance at this point (when it comes to HTTPS).